# How to solve the limit

Tags: calculus, limits, laurent-series

It should use Laurent's series, but the limit converges to $\infty$, hence there should be the substitute, but I don't know what to put as $t$:

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\Big[\Big(x^3-x^2+ \frac{x}{2}\Big)e^\frac{1}{x}-\sqrt{x^6+1}\Big]$$

Comment: Well... try $t=\frac1x$.

Comment: what do you mean with $$\infty+$$?

Comment: Actually $+\infty$, fixed a typo

Comment: If you expand $e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ as $1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{1}{6x^3}+o(\frac{1}{x^3})$ and $\sqrt{x^6+1}$ as $x^3+o(1)$, then you should be able to obtain the correct limit, $\frac{1}{6}$.